# Can't access apache website(s) from within home network but i can access them from outside home network

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, http-status-code-504

I wasn't having this problem up until a few days ago so I know that my setup *can* work. I had my friend try accessing one of my domains (from outside my network) and it worked for him. On one of my more complex websites where I host [Pterodactyl Panel](https://pterodactyl.io), I had him check the (browser) console and it gave him a

> 504 Gateway Timeout

I set the log level to `debug` in `apache2.conf` and when I tried to connect to my website, `errors.log` gets filled with:

```
[Thu Apr 23 12:11:13.651152 2020] [core:debug] [pid 28200] mpm_unix.c(684): (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH00056: connect to listener on [::]:80
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and send error log as code snippet, not an image.

Comment: I revised my question, thanks @Pmpr